# mongo query doesn't work with $ in field name

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Command to get raw_data:

```
db.raw_data.find({'cat':'like'},
    {'properties':1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5656b9a0c2492dec3442da52"),
    "properties" : {
        "subcategory" : "49",
        "$carrier" : "Vodafone India",
        "$radio" : "HSDPA",
        "$region" : "Gujarat",
        "$screen_width" : 375,
        "$wifi" : false,
        "mp_lib" : "iphone",
        "product_unlike_flag" : false,
        "mp_device_model" : "iPhone7,2",
        "user_id" : "4",
        "$city" : "Ahmedabad",
        "$manufacturer" : "Apple",
        "$os" : "iPhone OS",
        "brand" : "AO",
        "gender" : "Men",
        "mp_country_code" : "IN",
        "time" : 1445376786,
        "$app_release" : "0.8.0",
        "$lib_version" : "2.8.2",
        "$model" : "iPhone7,2",
        "$screen_height" : 667,
        "category" : "48",
        "$app_version" : "0.8.0",
        "$os_version" : "9.0.2",
        "itemcode" : "174",
        "source" : "Product"
    }
}
```

I want to extract user_id and city from this data.

I tried these Command :

Command1 :

```
db.raw_data.aggregate([{$group : {_id :{'user_id': "$properties.user_id","cat":"$cat","brand":"$properties.brand" } ,"num_tutorial" :{$sum:1}}} ,{ $project : {properties.$city : 1 } } ])
```

Command2:

```
db.raw_data.find({'cat':'like'},{'properties.$city':1})
```

which gave me an error:

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Positional projection 'properties.$city' does not match the query document.",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Is there any way/query so I can extract user-city relations from this data.

Comment: How did you populate the data in `raw_data` collection? As far as I know mongo will throw an uncaught exception `field names cannot start with $` if you do an `insert()` or `save()` for data with such properties.

Comment: @chridam try this : db.collection.insert({"properties":{"\uff04city":  "value"}})

Comment: @SarathNair Thanks for the input, methinks that's bad design if the application has properties that start with the reserved character used to represent operators.

Comment: @chridam Yeah sure it is.. I too agree

Comment: @chridam, I have imported data via mongoimport  with .json file which was containing lots of json data.

Answer (score 1):

In suck cases mongodb recommends to use [unicode](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#dollar-sign-operator-escaping) equivalent of '$'. This method is called $ sign escaping.

So your find query will look like following:

```
db.raw_data.find({'cat':'like'},{'properties.\uff04city':1})
```

Hope this helps :)

Result:

```
 > db.collection.find({},{'properties.\uff04city':1})
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5656e09ccb0a925b3d5d16f2"), "properties" : { "＄city" : "value" } }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5656e502cb0a925b3d5d16f3"), "properties" : { "＄city" : "value" } }
```

Comment: Its giving output like: { "_id" : ObjectId("5656b9a0c2492dec3442da52"), "properties" : { } }

Comment: It seems to work in my case. I have tried it on my machine. This is the only way that i can recall for extracting fields that start with $ using mongoDB query.